# Removing multiple character types from a string

Tags: scala

Is this an acceptable approach for removing multiple character types from a string or is there a better (more efficient way)? The `"ilr".contains(_)` bit feels a little like cheating considering it will be done for each and every character, but then again, maybe this is the right way. Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this?

```
val sentence = "Twinkle twinkle little star, oh I wander what you are"

val words = sentence.filter(!"ilr".contains(_))   

// Result: "Twnke twnke tte sta, oh I wande what you ae"
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There would be no significant difference, since there is only 3 characters to remove and no so big string to filter, but you may consider to use Set for this purpose. E.g.

```
val toRemove = "ilr".toSet
val words = sentence.filterNot(toRemove)
```

Comment: Thanks, this version is faster though: val toRemove = List( 'i', 'l', 'r');
        val words = sentence.filterNot(toRemove.contains(_))

Answer (score 34):

I'd just use Java's good old `replaceAll` (it takes a regexp):

```
"Twinkle twinkle little star, oh I wander what you are" replaceAll ("[ilr]", "")
// res0: String = Twnke twnke tte sta, oh I wande what you ae
```

In contrast to working with `char`s (as in filtering a `Seq[Char]`), using regular expressions should be Unicode-safe even if you're working with code points outside the basic multilingual plane. ["There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text."](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: You might have a point there on "outside the BMP". But if you care, you better get busy testing — there's *almost* no such thing as BMP-safe Java software (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2533118/53974).
Luckily, the SDK is apparently an exception, if you use the right APIs - and regexps are among the blessed ones.
http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/supplementary-142654.html