# How to convert big floats to int

Tags: java, php, int

I wrote a program in `java` and `php`. In which a `loop` runs `64` times. And keep adding `n to n`:

Java Code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double n = 1;
    double p = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i <= 64;i++){
        n = n + n;
        p = p + n;
    }
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $n = 1;
    $p = 0;
    for($i = 1;$i <= 64;$i++){
        $n = $n + $n;
        $p = $p + $n;
    }
    echo($p);

?>
```

And the output of both of these is:

`3.6893488147419E+19`

Now I want to know is it possible to convert this big float to int? if yes, Then how. In both languages.

Comment: Why use double for n and p in the first place?  Maybe you mean long?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415924/what-is-the-purpose-of-long-double-byte-char-in-java.  Also, if above what a 64 bit long can store, you can use java.math.BigInteger.  But again, this is integer addition.

Comment: You could use casting in Java to convert it I believe, but the easiest way is to, as @demongolem suggests, use the proper types in the first place.

Comment: 3.7 * 10^19 is well outside the range of an int. What output would you like?

Comment: @demongolem if I use the long instead of double it gives me output as `-1`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Have you ever heard of the trick 
`Put 1 rice grain on square 1 of a chess board. Double the grains on each successive square to square 64.` This is what I am trying to do. I want it be exact amount that I would get by the calculation on the paper.

Comment: Using `double` will not really get you the right answer.  The correct answer is an integer that takes 64 bits (which means `long` isn't good enough because of the sign bit).  A `double` only gives you 52 bits of precision, which means that if you use a `double` to do the computation, then no matter how you convert the result to an integer or `BigInteger`, the low-order 12 bits of the answer will not necessarily be accurate.

Comment: P.S. The right way to solve this is to go back to your high-school math class where they taught you how to sum a geometric progression :) :) :)

Comment: @ajb Well I am still in High School. My age is only (16 yrs). ;):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) type,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger n = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
    for(int i = 1;i <= 64;i++){
        n = n.add(n);
        p = p.add(n);
    }
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Output is

```
36893488147419103231
```

**Edit** Based on your comment, you really wanted something more like [The Legend of the Chessboard](http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/jbchessgrain.htm) -

```
BigInteger n = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger p = BigInteger.ZERO;
BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
for (int i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("For square #: " + i);
    sb.append(", Grains on square: " + n);
    p = p.add(n);
    n = n.multiply(TWO);
    sb.append(", Running Total: " + p);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: @mega6382 See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php) question.

Answer (score 1):

The number is too large to fit in a `long`. To get the closest integral approximation, convert the `double` to a `BigInteger` by way of a `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(p);
BigInteger bi = bd.toBigInteger();
```

However, to get an exact result, perform all the calculations using BigIntegers:

```
import static java.math.BigInteger.ONE;

BigInteger n = ONE;
BigInteger p = ONE;
for (int i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
    n = n.add(n);
    p = p.add(n);
}
System.out.println(p);
```

The difference between the approximate and exact values is:

```
36893488147419103000
36893488147419103231
```

Comment: how can you assure that this is exact.

Comment: Because the calculations are done with arbitrary precision integers, so there is no possibility of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Java: Math.round(float), PHP: round(value,precision)  However you will precision