# "2147483647" is excel default value?

Tags: java, excel

I'm uploading one .xlsx file with some values.
In my .xlsx file entered **2345678910** in cell.Next i'm uploaded but it is saved in database **2147483647** value.
Next time i'm uploaded with **8345678910** value but shows error.

ERROR:  Already **2147483647** value saved.

```
My Reg Exp:"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: " saved in database"!! what type of database?do you mean XLS file itself?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 10g. It is Excel problem or My java code problem?

Comment: what is the datatype of the field which you store this value in Oracle database? also remember that 2147483647  is the maximum value of int in java: see: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2124366

Comment: It is problem in my java code?. So how to retrive int to varchar in java.

Comment: to get  better help, post the source code of java; post the structure of the table; explain your problem in details.

Comment: int cannot store values larger than 2^31-1

Comment: And 2^31-1 = 2147483647, surprise surprise ;)
Use a long instead.

Comment: In database column datatype is varchar and in my code i'm using string.

Comment: Thanks for every one.It is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ktorn and many other commenters already commented with the answer. Use a `long` instead of an `int` ***in your Java code***. `int` cannot store values larger than 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647.

Comment: Hi i've small doubt.In my database i assigned **datatype** is varchar(255) for one field. In java i'm using **long** for getting value. Which one is best **long** or **double**.  I want allow numeric values,special charecters and all...

Comment: Use `long` if you want only integers, `double` if you want to include decimals. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415924/what-is-the-purpose-of-long-double-byte-char-in-java.